# Find index pair with fewest number of entries in Multiindex data frame

Tags: python, pandas, count, multi-index

Given a pandas data frame with a 3 (or more) level index.
e.g.:

```
             foo1 foo2 ...
L1  L2  L3
A   a   1    ...  ...
        2    ...  ...
    b   3    ...  ...
B   a   2    ...  ...
        2    ...  ...
        1    ...  ...
C   a   5    ...  ...
        3    ...  ...
    c   0    ...  ...
        9    ...  ...
```

I want to find the pair `L1` & `L2` with the fewest number of entries, i.e. `(A,b)` in above example because it only has one entry: `(A,b,3)`

My idea was to perform some kind of aggregation on `L1` and `L2` but I don't think you can make it work on indices. Of course I could access the index values and then loop over them to count entries but I feel that there is a more pandas-ish and more elegant solution.

Comment: do you want to get the combination with the minimal number of entries overall, (i.e. a single result par dataframe) or for each L1 or L2?

Comment: The first - so one combination L1 L2 that has the fewest entries (L3 and below levels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `groupby`+`size` you can get the number of rows per group:

```
df.groupby(level=['L1','L2']).size()
```

Output:

```
L1  L2
A   a     2
    b     1
B   a     3
C   a     2
    c     2
```

If you add `idxmin`, you can get identify the group with the least number of rows:

```
df.groupby(level=['L1','L2']).size().idxmin()
```

Output: `('A', 'b')`